# How to Create Webview in Laravel or ReactJS (WebApplication)

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-dusk

I want to open another web page in my single page. I try iframe,embed ,httprequest but not safely and not working. How can I create this page ? I develop winform application before and use cefsharp. This very basicly. But web application not supported this operation. I found Laravel Dusk but not this was not what I was looking for. Laravel Dusk run background and automation system. I think, I should use javascript framework but I can't open antoher webpage inside. I tryed use HttpRequest, download web page download and parse html but not work functions.